# Best way to map types of two params of one function (And ensure type safety in the mapping type)

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a enum like this:

```
export enum testEnum {
  key1 = "val1",
  key2 = "val2"
}
```

and I have a function that the first param is `testEnum` type, the second param will be some other type base on which enum was passed in the first param. And I use this:

```
testFunc<T extends `${testEnum}`>(
    param1: T,
    param2: paramMapType[T],
  ): Promise<void>
```

and a type use for mapping:

```
type paramMapType = {
  val1: string;
  val2: boolean
};
```

the problem now is that in paramMapType there are no type safety that the keys will be one of the values of `testEnum`. I tried

```
type paramMapType = {
  [key in `${testEnum}`]: any
  val1: string;
  val2: boolean
};
```

but got this err: `A mapped type may not declare properties or methods.`

How can I suppose to implement that kind of type safety in `paramMapType`

I used [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) but it kind of long in syntax and yet have no type safety for the typeMap

Comment: You don't need to... it will error if the map is missing a key: https://tsplay.dev/mZQjEN

Comment: @caTS Oh thank you, I got that error before but had no idea what it means. Now read again and it make sense :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check, that there are only keys in the `paramMapType` from the `testEnum` enum by checking the type during type definition.

```
type paramMapType = Check<`${testEnum}`, {
  val1: string;
  val2: boolean
}>
```

The check will be implemented as follows:

```
type Check<Keys, Object> = Exclude<keyof Object, Keys> extends never ? Object : never
```

The check will return the same type in case there is no extra key in `Object` that is not present in the enum.

Then, if you would redefine the type `paramMapType`, for example like this:

```
type paramMapType = Check<`${testEnum}`, {
  val1: string;
  val2: boolean;
  val3: number;
}>
```

The compiler would resolve the `paramMapType` to never and then the second parameter of `testFunc` would be never. As you can't find an instance of never type, calling never with some literal value wouldn't compile.

Comment: I don't think this is necessary as it already errors: https://tsplay.dev/mZQjEN

Comment: yes but you can add another `val3` in `paramMapType` and it won't

Comment: But i did simplify the check so because the missing key in `paramMapType` is already handled by the `paramMapType[T]`

Comment: I think @ryskajakub is some kind of nice-to-have. I will apply your solution to my project. Thank you guys !!